# Adding modules in Pytorch Custom Module

Tags: python, pytorch

Is it considered bad practice to add modules to a custom pytorch `nn.Module` using `self.add_module()`? All of the documentation seems to assign the layers to properties, then access them in the `forward()` method.

For example:

```
class ConvLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_module('conv',nn.Conv2d(...))
        self.add_module('bn',nn.BatchNorm2d(...))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `add_module` will add an entry to the `_modules` dict. The `Module` class also overwrites `__getattr__` so that when you try to access a layer, it will look inside the `_modules` dict, despite the fact that the layer is not actually an attribute of the object. But from the user's perspective, it doesn't make a difference whether `module.layer` returns an actual property or simply an element from some private dict.